# DateComponentsFormatter not honoring formattingContext

Tags: swift, nsdatecomponentsformatter

When I use a standard `NumberFormatter`, it honors the `formattingContext` of `.beginningOfSentence`:

```swift
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
formatter.formattingContext = .beginningOfSentence
let string = formatter.string(for: 5)                 // "Five"; good
```

But when I try this with `DateComponentsFormatter`, it seems to ignore the `formattingContext`:

```swift
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .spellOut
formatter.formattingContext = .beginningOfSentence
let string = formatter.string(from: 5 * 60)           // "five minutes"; bad, should be "Five minutes"
```

FWIW, I tried a variety of permutations, all to no avail:

- Tested different locales to make sure it was not just a bug in a particular locale (e.g., I tried both English and French, it localizes correctly, but does not capitalize correctly);
- Tested in macOS and various iOS versions (to make sure it was not unique to a particular platform/version);
- Tried changing the order in which I set `unitsStyle` and `formattingContext`;
- Tried explicitly setting `allowedUnits` and `maximumUnitCount` in case it was getting confused by the potentially variable number of units/components represented by the string; and
- Tried a variety of `formattingContext` options (not just `.beginningOfSentence`) and they all just return the same lowercased string.

I have worked-around the immediate problem by just applying my own sentence capitalization to the string. But I just want to ensure I am not missing something obvious before I file a bug report. Looks like `DateComponentsFormatter` simply does not honor `formattingContext`.

Comment: Filed bug report FB10885005.

Comment: I have the opposite problem: When using the `includesApproximationPhrase` option together with the `middleOfSentence` context, I always get a capitalized string.